# Spring Boot with Jetty error

Tags: java, ajax, spring, spring-boot

I have an web application using Spring Boot and a jetty server. I am making calls through ajax but instead of them getting mapped to my Spring Controller they are resulting in an error.

The error:

```
2016-06-16 18:55:25.450  WARN 11772 --- [tp1170788511-19] o.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler   : Error for /test
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpMethod
```

and:

```
2016-06-16 18:55:25.451  WARN 11772 --- [tp1170788511-19] o.e.jetty.server.AbstractHttpConnection  : /test
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/eclipse/jetty/http/HttpMethod
```

The Ajax:

```
 $.ajax({
    url: "/test",
    type: "POST",
    async: false,,
    success: function (response) {
    ...
    }
```

The Controller:

```
@Controller
public class LoginController {

@RequestMapping(value="/test", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String countingForm(Model model) {
    System.out.println("test");
    return "test";
}
```

}

If anyone could shine some light on whats going wrong that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No luck on this problem? I have the exact same error now.

Answer (score 2):

Did you excluded tomcat from spring-boot-starter-web?

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jetty</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't affect anything.

Comment: Ok. Spring-boot should work with Jetty without any problems. Did you excluded Tomcat from spring-boot-starter-web?
I've eddited my answer

Comment: and by the way. I see two commans in your JS    `'async: false,,`